# 16.04 won't boot after latest updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04

I bought a Dell 17-5755 ten days ago and have been slowly configuring it. Came with Win 8.1, which I first upgraded to Win 10. Then shrank the primary partition to make room for Ubu and installed 16.04. Both have been running fine for the last week.

Yesterday, I started shifting over to the new machine in earnest, setting up Thunderbird and migrating from Evolution. While I was doing this, a notification popped up for a software update, so I started the software updater in the background and ignored it. I thought I had auto update off and don't remember pressing install, but next I looked it had updated and was asking to restart, so I've no idea what the updates were. I was in the middle of something, so pressed restart later. Later came and I restarted from the shutdown menu. The grub menu came up as usual, but I can't boot to Ubuntu and get the following:

```
/dev/sda6: recovery journal

/dev/sda6: clean, 229524/107610112 files, 10311615/430426112 blocks

[   10.174300] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x9d899000-0x9d899fff]
```

Then it hangs, but something is going on as the fan starts winding up 10-15 seconds later. At this point all I can do it hard power off.

Win 10 still boots fine. The Ubu kernel is still 4.4.0-22, the same as before the updates. I guess I'm looking at starting over with a reinstall of 16.04, but any advice before I do that is much appreciated.

Comment: Update: Have tried to boot from a 16.04 usb stick. I don't get the error, but it hangs on the purple ubuntu screen.  Starting to look like a hardware fault that occurred coincidentally.

Comment: It's also hanging for me with this error when booting from a 16.04 USB stick on a Dell Inspiron 7000 series.

Comment: Same problem here, and with a Dell as well.

Comment: The problem has returned for me too. Have never found an effective fix, so I'm stuck using Windows at present.

Comment: Maybe some issue with EFI mode? I think it should be enable while you install Ubuntu 16.04 and later, in order to keep dual boot working with W10. You can check it on the BIOS

Comment: @ChesuCR, thanks. UEFI was enabled the whole time, for the Win 8 to Win 10 upgrade, followed by the dual boot install of 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem with Dell Inspiron i7559-763BLK this morning.

I think it is not related to dual boot or hardware fault.

As I understand this problem is related to one of the kernel modules which was built for earlier kernel version. After kernel upgrade you need to rebuild this module or install newer version.

Check what kernel modules you have installed last week with your software (e.g. drivers).

In my case upgrading to a newer nvidia drivers solved the issue.

What I did is reboot in recovery mode, uninstalled the nvidia proprietary drivers, and installed the latest one from [graphics-drivers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install nvidia-378
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a Radeon R5 card not NVIDIA and it was running fine for a week, so probably not the same issue?

Comment: Updated the answer: As I understand this problem is related to one of the kernel modules which was built for earlier kernel version. After kernel upgrade you need to rebuild this module or install newer version. Check what kernel modules you have installed last week with your software (e.g. drivers).

Answer (score 0):

The problem must appear after install some nvidia drivers.

In my case, I'd installed nvidia-361 drivers. But the solution for this problem that I found was different. When the authentication failed, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and I realized that the 'PATH' variable was not set with the correctly (`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin', etc`). Because of this even 'ls' command was not working anymore. So, I decide simply to set the 'PATH' variable and everything worked again.

Comment: «simply to set the 'PATH' variable and everything worked again» Good. It would be good to include directions on this part in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I persistently saw this problem with nvidia-384 driver. Each time I reboot, I got stuck at the same point. The only way I got the system to boot was by purging the Nvidia drivers in recovery mode. My system configuration is Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.10 0-041000-generic.

However when I installed an older version nvidia-381, I was not getting stuck on boot. Its just likely that the newest version of nvidia drivers is buggy.